# Get list of users from file for powershell loop

Tags: powershell, loops

I'm trying to modify this PowerShell script to allow input of users from a text or CSV file. I've pulled the script directly from [Tim Rhymer](https://interworks.com/blog/trhymer/2014/01/22/powershell-get-last-logon-all-users-across-all-domain-controllers/).

This is the original script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon() {
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
  $time = 0
  $exportFilePath = "c:lastLogon.csv"
  $columns = "name,username,datetime"

  Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Force -InputObject $columns

  foreach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($dc in $dcs) { 
      $hostname = $dc.HostName
      $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon

      if ($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) {
        $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
      }
    }

    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    $row = $user.Name + "," + $user.SamAccountName + "," + $dt

    Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -NoClobber -InputObject $row

    $time = 0
  }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

I'm thinking I should modify the portion of the script the sets the variable of `$user` and how the `foreach ($user in $users)` loop processes each user, but can't figure it out.

Comment: i would not gather the DC list, OR get the User list, OR write to the output file **_inside_** the function. the usual method is to do ONE THING in a function. hand the function a list of DCs & a list of Users. let if gather the info, build a `PSCustomObject` of the details you want, and then send that out as each user is completed. let the calling script handle writing the file - and giving it a `PSCustomObject` means that the `Export-CSV` cmdlet will handle sending things for you - no manual header building, no manual row building ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

As for this...

> allow input of users from a text or CSV file.

… that is all that this is...

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
```

… You just replace that with your file

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path $UncToUserList.csv
```

Yet, by your question, since this is a really common, basic PowerShell thing, I am assuming you are very new to this and would advise really ramping up on PowerShell using all the freely available learning resources on [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/183.windows-powershell-survival-guide.aspx) [MVA](https://mva.microsoft.com), [MSChannel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell#ch9Search&lang-en=en&pubDate=year) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell), as well as freely available [eBooks](https://powershell.org/ebooks), as to avoid much confusion and frustration in your learning cycles as possible.

Also, you should never run any untrusted code, or code you do not fully understand. Use only in a test environment that you can fully recover from before ever considering production runs to avoid things that can cause you to have an RPE error --- 'Resume Producing Event'.