# Catch error from Get-ADObject server timeout

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory

When I run this script from [Tim Rhymer](https://interworks.com/blog/trhymer/2014/01/22/powershell-get-last-logon-all-users-across-all-domain-controllers/) I get errors from some of my domain controllers where the server times out for some reason. When I receive the error below, it stalls the script for 15-30 seconds, rather than the query for the domain controller taking 1-2 seconds. How can I catch the error and not stall the script for so long? Below is the section of the

Error Message:

```
Get-ADObject : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server
does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory
Web Services running.
At C:\Users\jimbob\AD_Lookup.ps1:58 char:54
+ ... countName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastlogon <# - ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=jimbob...DC=domaincontroller,DC=com:User) [Get-ADObject], ADServerDownException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject
```

Below is the script that queries domain controllers to get the lastlogon date from all domain controllers.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon() {
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $users = Get-ADUser -Filter *
  $time = 0
  $exportFilePath = "c:lastLogon.csv"
  $columns = "name,username,datetime"

  Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Force -InputObject $columns

  foreach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($dc in $dcs) { 
      $hostname = $dc.HostName
      $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName | Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon

      if ($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) {
        $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
      }
    }

    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    $row = $user.Name + "," + $user.SamAccountName + "," + $dt

    Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -NoClobber -InputObject $row

    $time = 0
  }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

I think I need to change something to catch the error or bypass the issue causing the error from one of the following portions of the script:

```
$dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
```

or

```
$currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName |
               Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon
```

Comment: is there a reason for posting the same script in two threads? ///// Get list of users from file for powershell loop - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689163/get-list-of-users-from-file-for-powershell-loop

Comment: to directly address your question, add a test on the DC list to check for availability, OR add a check just before the G-ADO call, OR add a delay if the problem is too many calls all at once.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the error you're getting an `ADServerDownException`. You can catch and handle specific exceptions like this:

```
try {
    $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName |
                   Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon
} catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException] {
    # handle AD server unreachable
} catch {
    # handle all other exceptions
}
```

The blanket `catch` at the end can be omitted, if you want all other exceptions to just bubble up to the caller instead of handling them yourself.

This won't, however, speed up your code, because the exception will only be thrown *after* the timeout occurred. To decrease the execution time of your code you could

- check whether the server is accessible before trying to interact with it, e.g.

  ```
  if (Test-Connection -Computer $hostname -Count 2 -Quiet) {
      $currentUser = ...
      ...
  }
  ```
- use [background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/background-jobs) to run the operations in parallel

  ```
  $jobs = foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
      Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
          Param($username, $hostname)
          Get-ADUser $username |
              Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon
      } -ArgumentList $user.SamAccountName, $dc.HostName
  }
  $jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
  $jobs | Remove-Job
  ```

However, arguably the biggest bottleneck in your code is that it first gets all users from AD (`Get-ADUser -Filter *`), then queries each user individually *again* for each DC (`Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName`), *then* runs the actual query against the particular DC (`Get-ADObject`).

You should be able to speed up the code considerably by running just a single query for all users against each DC. Group the results by `SamAccountName` and pick the record with the most recent timestamp from each group, then export the results to a CSV.

```
$fltr  = '(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))'
$props = 'SamAccountName', 'LastLogon'

Get-ADDomainController -Filter * |
    Select-Object -Expand HostName |
    Where-Object { Test-Connection -Computer $_ -Count 2 -Quiet } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $fltr -Properties $props -Server $_ } |
    Select-Object Name, SamAccountName,
        @{n='LastLogon';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} |
    Group-Object SamAccountName |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort-Object LastLogon | Select-Object -Last 1 } |
    Export-Csv $exportFilePath -NoType
```